# mySQL Populate DB Column using calculated value from anouther table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

What I am trying to do is have a field called 'age' autopopulate from a persons date of birth when a row is added - the trick is the persons date of birth resides in anouther field.

My two tables are:

student

> student_id (PK), first_name, last_name, date_of_birth

fitness_report

> report_id (PK), test_date, test_period, age_tested, student_id (FK)

ideally the age_tested will be caluclated from the test_period however happy to use ()NOW as that'll be within reasonable limits.

Obviously what i need to do here is create a trigger - but not sure on the SELECT statement to get the age to populate.  Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't store the age in the fitness_report. You have the date tested and the student dob so you can always calculate the age_tested when you need it.

Comment: If your are asking for the SELECT that means you are asking how to calculate the age based on a given date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rwilliams said, it is not advisable to store the age_tested as it is redundant but if it is what you want to do you can wrap a simple trigger around Mosty's solution -

```
CREATE TRIGGER fitness_report_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `fitness_report`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    SET NEW.age_tested = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NEW.test_period, '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(student.date_of_birth, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NEW.test_period, '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(student.date_of_birth, '00-%m-%d')) FROM student WHERE student.student_id = NEW.student_id);

END
```

This assumes that test_period is a date as previously mentioned by Mosty. I have not tried this as I do not have access to a server right now so it may need a little tweaking.

UPDATE: You could try the following as a starting point for your stats -

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(test_period, '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(test_period, '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, '00-%m-%d')) AS age,
    s.gender,
    AVG(r.score) AS score
FROM student s
INNER JOIN fitness_report r 
    ON s.student_id = r.student_id
GROUP BY age, s.gender
```

Comment: Hmm I see the points about not storing age.
In which case maybe you can help me with what I am trying to achieve big picture.

Here is my anticipated logical design: http://webjunction.com.au/Logical.pdf

I am thinking of removing the statistics table now and building a series of SELECT statements.  

I want to be able to pull average statistics for each Test based on Age and Gender.

Could you suggest a select statement to pull the average score for males aged 12? (from there I will be able to figure out the rest)

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'r.score' in 'field list' on the stats select statement

Comment: Ahh - The issue is that score lays in a seperate table to fitness_report and student, it lays in a third table result.

Comment: So you just need to add the extra join to your result table.  If you need further help I suggest you post the full structure for each of the tables involved.

Comment: the full structure is here: webjunction.com.au/Logical.pdf - Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get current age:

```
select s.name, s.date_of_birth,
  date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(date_of_birth, '%Y') - 
  (date_format(now(), '00-%m-%d') < date_format(date_of_birth, '00-%m-%d'))
as age
from s
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95418/3)

This is how to get age up to the test_period (shouldn't it be test_date?):

```
select s.name, s.date_of_birth, r.test_period,
  date_format(test_period, '%Y') - date_format(date_of_birth, '%Y') - 
  (date_format(test_period, '00-%m-%d') < date_format(date_of_birth, '00-%m-%d'))
as age
from r
join s on s.id_student = r.student_id
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95418)